# c++ how declare function returning vector of objects

Tags: c++, object, vector

and I struggle with function which should return vector of objects but for some reason it throws errors all the time, telling that my object is undeclared identifier and vector of this objects is not valid template and points me to .h file where I declare function.
I will appropriate any explanation what that mean and how to fix this. bellow I place code from my class and starting files.

```
#ifndef SETUPW_H
#define SETUPW_H
#include"Square.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

std::vector<std::ifstream> allText();
std::ifstream loadTxt(std::string txt);
void printByLine(std::ifstream& txt);
std::vector<square> allSquares();//compiler points me to this line and that one bellow
void whichSQ(int sqNum, std::vector<square> sq);

#endif
```

and  my class:

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H
#include"player.h"
#include"setupW.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

class square
{
public:
     square(std::string name, int sqNumber, std::string description, int exits, int object);
    void loadSQ(std::ifstream& inFile);
    void printSQ();

private:
    int mSqNumber;
    std::string mName;
    std::string mDescription;
    int mExits;
    int mObject;
};

#endif
```

Comment: `std::vector` requires the class to be copyable. Just define a copy constructor.

Comment: Your header guards are wrong in the first snippet. And `square.h` shouldn't include `setupW.h` if that's the first snippet.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, all classes are copyable (perhaps not logically correct) unless explicitly made non-copyable.

Comment: And what is the **exact** error?

Comment: @StoryTeller, he defined one construction but didnt define the copy constructor. Thus his class is not copyable.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal the compiler automatically creates one if not told otherwise and if all members are copyable

Comment: exact error is:
setupw.h(12): error C2065: 'square' : undeclared identifier
setupw.h(12): error C2923: 'std::vector' : 'square' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

Comment: @SzarleyDwarf were your guards wrong or right (im aksing because you edited the snippet)? A wrong header guard would explain the problem.

Comment: @Paranaix there was missing letter in guard but after correction I still get same error

Comment: Could you post the includes of the compilation unit causing the error as you have a circular dependency? My guess is that the problem arises if `square.h` is included before `setupW.h` (notice the include in `square.h`). In that case the function would be declared before `square` is declared.

Comment: You include setupW.h before declaring the class square, at least for code that includes Square.h. That cannot work.

Comment: @Paranaix sorry but I don't know what you mean, like I said I'm new in c++, could you please tell me what you want me to include in other words

Comment: @SzarleyDwarf The includes (`#include xyz...`) of the `.cpp` file causing the error (the compiler compiles single `.cpp` files independely).

Comment: @Paranaix here are includes from setupW.cpp
#include"setupW.h"
#include"Square.h"

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
and here are from  square.cpp
#include"Square.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because you have a circular dependency here. In `square.cpp` you firstly include `square.h`. But `square.h` contains this line `#include"setupW.h"` (before your class declaration). Therefor the declarations of your functions will appear before the declaration of your `square` class. That causes the compiler to mutter that `square` is not declared (at that time) when he reads `std::vector<square>`.

The most easiest solution would be to simply remove the include, because it is, as far as I can tell, unneccessary.

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot. I was quite sure that I need to include all my .h files in all others, if you know what I mean. I didn't realize that this can cause problems. Thanks again.

Comment: @SzarleyDwarf A good approach is to keep includes to a minimum, only include files you really need in the header file. E.g if you want to declare a `std::string` member in your header file, you will have to include it there, but if you only need `std::string` in your implementation then include it in the .cpp file and not in your header file

Comment: Thank you for that, now I will know for future to don't include all .h in other files :)